# I run on the edge of a diamond

Tags: riddle, word, language

I have a lot of friends with the same name as me, but we're all different.

I love to swim and dive.

You might find me at a ball game, at a festival, or lying down outside.

I changed my name when I became old.

I run on the edge of a diamond

and hold court outside.

What am I?

**Hint 1**

> I am a noun, verb, and adjective, and my noun and verb forms can be identical (conjugation).

**Hint 2**

> I'm usually green.

Answer (score 7):

You are:

> Grass

I have a lot of friends with the same name as me, but we're all different.

> There are many varieties of grass

I love to swim and dive.

> Blades of grass can float, and grass can grow under water

You might find me at a ball game, at a festival, or lying down outside.

> Each of these are in grassy areas

I changed my name when I became old.

> Seed->Bud->Grass

I run on the edge of a diamond

> Grass surrounds a baseball diamond

and hold court outside.

> Reference to grassy courtyards

*Hint 1*

> Noun/Verb = Grass, Adjective = Grassy

Answer (score 2):

**EDITED**

Are you a:

> Pavillion

I have a lot of friends with the same name as me, but we're all different.

> There are many names of shades similar to a pavilion, eg tent

I love to swim and dive.

> Unsure

You might find me at a ball game, at a festival, or lying down outside.

> -A cricket pavilion
>  -A pavilion at fairs/festivals
>  -possibly an unassembled pavilion?

I changed my name when I became old.

> The root of pavilion comes from papilo, which also means butterfly, hence the
>  change/evolution to pavilion

I run on the edge of a diamond

> Pavilion runs around the sides of a diamond

and hold court outside.

> Unsure

Comment: I like this answer a lot, but if you know what I am, it will be obvious why I changed my name.

Answer (score 2):

Are you a

> Play

I have a lot of friends with the same name as me, but we're all different.

> There are a lot of plays: different genres like comedy, tragedy, etc.

I love to swim and dive.

> Swimming and diving are sports and you can play them (crude)

You might find me at a ball game, at a festival, or lying down outside.

> Plays in a ball game, plays in a festival, playing outside (crude, again)

I changed my name when I became old.

> I'm not sure on this one

I run on the edge of a diamond

> Reference to baseball, where the player runs at the edge of a diamond to score a run. That is considered a play.

and hold court outside.

> To hold court  is to play (I've seen the phrase used in tennis)

Previous answer:

> Player (wrong)

Comment: 2 of these answers are spot on, but the word is not right. I'll try to add a hint which helps narrow things down.

Answer (score 2):

What am I?

> A school?

I have a lot of friends with the same name as me, but we're all different.

> grammar school, school of art, catholic school etc.?

I love to swim and dive.

> a school of fish

You might find me at a ball game, at a festival, or lying down outside.

> school ball-game, school festival, that scene from cheezy american movies about college students

I changed my name when I became old.

> Nursery/pre-school > Infants/Primary > Juniors/Primary > Seniors > College/Highschool > University

I run on the edge of a diamond

> Diamond school? The diamond edge model?

and hold court outside.

> School court yard?

Answer (score 2):

Are you a

> Light?

I have a lot of friends with the same name as me, but we're all different.

> There are many "lights," red, blue, ultraviolet, **green.**

I love to swim and dive.

> Many maritime vehicles, such as boats and submarines, have a green, white and red light affixed to the hull for navigation purposes.  Also, traffic lights hanging from a line in the wind may "swim" or "dive."

You might find me at a ball game, at a festival, or lying down outside.

> Stadium lights, festival lights, lawn lights

I changed my name when I became old.

> Lights used to be known as "lamps." (I'm stretching here, maybe)

I run on the edge of a diamond

> Baseball runners run on the edge of a baseball diamond, and are sometimes given the "green light" to proceed to the next base.

and hold court outside

> Traffic lights have authority to make cars stop, yield, or pass freely, judging them in "traffic intersection court." :)

Hint 1

> "I light the light and now my room is very light" verb, noun, adjective

Hint 2

> I wouldn't say that lights are "usually" green, but there certainly are lots of green lights around: Traffic lights all have a green phase, green LEDs, metaphorically giving the "green light," etc. etc. Also, in current times, most of the lights that you buy are energy efficient, or green.

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> Pitch?

I have a lot of friends with the same name as me, but we're all different.

> Pitch for sound, Pitching a baseball, Pitching an idea, etc.

I love to swim and dive.

> Thinking about a sound wave (waves also helps with the idea of swimming and diving), the pitch goes up and down giving the notion swimming and diving.

You might find me at a ball game, at a festival, or lying down outside.

> Ball game - Pitching a baseball, Festival - Pitching a tent, Lying down outside - a football pitch is usually outdoors.

I changed my name when I became old.

> Pitch is used in the UK and field is used in the US?

I run on the edge of a diamond

> A baseball field is shaped like a diamond. The ball is pitched around the diamond?

and hold court outside.

> Not sure about this one.